# How does Tunnel Fighter interact with Paladin's Relentless Avenger?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, movement, opportunity-attack, unearthed-arcana

With the Tunnel Master fighting style (from [Unearthed Arcana: Light, Dark, Underdark!](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/02_UA_Underdark_Characters.pdf)), a character can use a bonus action to take a defensive stance that lets them make opportunity attacks without expending a reaction.

The [Oath of Vengeance paladin](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/paladin#OathofVengeance) gets the Relentless Avenger feature at 7th level (PHB, p. 88); when he makes an opportunity attack, he can move up to half his speed as a part of the reaction used to make the attack.

Can a character in a Defensive Stance with Relentless Avenger move with every opportunity attack? Can he move only once, expending his reaction, while still having unlimited opportunity attacks otherwise?

Comment: somewhat related: [Tunnel Fighter & Polearm Master...](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/72261/23970)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you stated, Relentless Avenger allows you to move your speed *as part of the reaction* used on the Opportunity Attack.  You are not expending a reaction when you use Tunnel Master's defensive stance to make opportunity attacks, thus you cannot move.

**Can a character in a Defensive Stance with Relentless Avenger move with every opportunity attack?**

No, because he is not using his reaction to make those opportunity attacks, and Relentless Avenger requires it.

**Can he move only once, expending his reaction, while still having unlimited opportunity attacks otherwise?**

I would say maybe, but you should ask your DM.  In the spirit of Tunnel Master, probably not, because in my mind, a defensive stance means you aren't moving.